# A better way to show different wpf pages in mainWindow?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have several Wpf pages in my project, these pages have different forms and ui control indide theme. The image below shows the mainWindow and there are two button.
I want to show a specific page when I click on + or Edit button using the Frame control which is highlighted.

apparenatly this woks:

```
Page1 me = new Page1(); 
mainFrame.Content = me;
```

But it has an IE navigation sound and a toolbar appears after going to page2.
any better way to show diffrent pages and not using a frame?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to convert the `Page` into a `UserControl`.  You can then put that control inside some other container, such as a `Grid`.  You'll have to manually swap out the pages in the container when navigating, but it looks like you're doing that anyway.

Comment: YoteXP  gives the solution

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `Frame` control is to allow navigation. If you don't want navigation, then don't use `Frame`. You can turn off the navigation toolbar, but that won't actually disable navigation - there are mouse buttons and keyboard shortcuts for navigating back.

If you just want to host a UI element without navigation, use something simpler, like a `Border` element - put the content in its `Child` property. You can change the `Child` as many times as you like at runtime.

Comment: I get this error: "Page can have only Window or Frame as parent."

Comment: I assume that YotaXP's answer fixes the problem you've raised in your comment?

Comment: Not quite sure why someone downvoted this. (It has a +1 and a -1 as I write this.) What I've written is correct, and the problem that @Alexandergre raised in response is completely solved by YotaXP's suggestion. So solution here is the *combination* of what I said (don't put it in a Frame), and what @YotaXP said (don't make it a Page). If whoever voted me down sees my reply, could you please add a comment saying what you think was wrong about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set the frame control's NavigationUIVisibility to Hidden.  This solved the problem for me.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 though so it might not be applicable to older VS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ian Griffiths, what you suggest increases the workload on the developer substantially. And you are stepping outside of the underlying paradigm of XAML.

In my case I'm developing a game application and have chosen WPF as the UI platform as much as possible. For me that means a intro screen, character select, etc. The purpose of Pages is to encapsulate the navigational need of such an application.

I suspect your downvote is due to your statement "If you don't want navigation...". Upon re-reading the original posters question I see he *does* want navigation, he just wants it on his own terms. I would have voted you down too. YotaXP's solution neglects the issues with using a User Control, particularly if it may contain other User Controls. It looks like Chris Calvert came up with an actual solution to the poster's issue within the parameters of the problem.

I would be curios if I could override the navigation hotkeys and such within the existing paragimn but that's properly in its own thread.

Comment: What substantial extra work? Setting a `UserControl` as the content of a `Border` takes exactly the same amount of code (1 line) as setting a `Page` as the content of a `Frame`. The only difference is that with a `Frame`, you get navigation support. The question was complaining about the navigation features. (I really don't see how you've concluded that he wants navigation, particularly given the answer he accepted.) Note that I also pointed out that he had the option to turn off just the navigation toolbar (and Chris Calvert provided more detail) if he wanted navigation without the buttons.